# Resizing background image based on browser window size (HTML, CSS)

Tags: css, html, background, gradient

I am trying to have my background gradient fill the available "real estate" of the browser window. [Here is an example of what is currently happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe7tz.png) I've copied and pasted the related code, please let me know if I'm missing any info you need!

I have tried the methods listed [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) but none of them have worked for me. Any other suggestions, or am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

```css
.mainbody {
  background: linear-gradient(#42f4d7, #f4425f) no-repeat center center fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbody"></div>
```

Comment: I converted your code to snippet. Try to do that form now on. I know you're new, just trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option at your disposal is to apply this gradient to the `body`, not the `div`.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#42f4d7, #f4425f) no-repeat center center fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbody"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! I knew there had to be an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

set the height to 100% or change the body tag to cover the entire height as per @SergChernata :)

```css
.mainbody {
  background: linear-gradient(#42f4d7, #f4425f) no-repeat center center fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbody"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding height: 100% however has messed up my other pages - now the gradient background ends partway through my longer pages.

Comment: it needs to be on the over-arching div - or the body

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to set the height and width of your element to 100% and then it will cover all the screen size of any device. Of course, if it is an absolute element it has to be related to something that already has the size of the window. Right now the size will be 100% of the closest parent with "position: relative" attributed to it. if you want to make sure it will actually be 100% of the screen, just make sure none of its parents has the "position: relative" attribute. You can set them to "position: static" if you want to be sure.

```css
.mainbody {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#42f4d7, #f4425f);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbody"></div>
```